# how to delete value from database if it is not present in the array

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

```
db.query('DELETE FROM position WHERE position <> ALL ($1)',[req.body.positionDetails.position],function(err,data){
  if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
  console.log('deleted')                            
})
```

Here I want to delete `position` value from the database which is not present in the array.

The array is like:

```
{
   "positionDetails":[
      {
         "position":"developer",
         "fullTime":"true",
         "unit":"er",
         "office_country":"india",
         "office_city":"gyu",
         "technology":"ghj",
         "framework":"fgb",
         "position_start":"1-2-2012",
         "position_end":"3-12-2020",
         "company_id":"1",
         "monthly_target":"200",
         "wage":"sdfg"
      },
      {
         "position":"manager",
         "fullTime":"true",
         "unit":"er",
         "office_country":"india",
         "office_city":"gyu",
         "technology":"ghj",
         "framework":"fgb",
         "position_start":"1-2-2012",
         "position_end":"3-12-2020",
         "company_id":"1",
         "monthly_target":"200",
         "wage":"sdfg"
      }
   ]
}
```

But it is deleting all the values from the database how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

```
var anyvalue=""
data.positionDetails.position.map((item,i)=>{
    if(item == DELETE_ITEM) {
        anyvalue += item+","
    }     
})
```

NOTE : You have to remove last `,` from `anyvalue` by using trim or anyother functionality.

```
db.query('DELETE FROM position WHERE position IN (anyvalue),[data.positionDetails.position],function(err,data){
  if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
  console.log('deleted')                            
})
```

As postionDetail have position field which will delete specific position object.

Comment: If the array contains multiple values??

Comment: i m updating my answer just check once

Comment: in your answer you are checking for "=" means the data which is present in the array is get deleted right??